# How do I track the total number of kills for a person - like number of goblins killed

Tags: rec-room

Would like to track total number of kills of goblins for a person and hang onto the number.  Looks like I store the number in the scoreboard for later use - next time the person plays.

And each time a wave of spawned AI is killed it can send a one out.  But now to add them all up....    And then get it into a stat that is persistent the next time the player plays.

Comment: I don't think that there is currently a way to determine which player kills an AI - unless you have custom weapons, e.g. something based on the rangefinder.